# IndentationError: expected an indented block when trying to reproduce LDA for a document

Tags: python, pandas, lda

I am trying to obtain the LDA distribution among the first article of my collection but I am running into several errors:

my collection: `doc_set`, is a `pandas.core.series.Series`. Whenever I wanted to run the simple code:

```
print(ldamodel[doc_set[1]])
```

I run the following error: `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` Which I think I solved it by:

```
if doc_set is not None:
print(ldamodel[doc_set[1]])
```

Nevertheless, now I get the following error: `IndentationError: expected an indented block`. I am looking for the intuition of the error rather than the correction, I cannot put my whole LDA for reproduction because it is too massive. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whitespace is crucial in Python.  Every block must be indented.  You said `if ...`, so presumably you want to put something in that block.  Since you didn't indent your `print` call, Python thinks you didn't put anything in the block.  Just indent that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indentation is incorrect because you didn't put your `print` statement inside the `if` block. If you end the line with a colon (`:`), you have to increase the indent level, or else you'll get an `IndentationError` exception.
This would be the correct code:

```
if doc_set is not None:
    print(ldamodel[doc_set[1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

indentation are very peculiar in python. You have to maintain the heirarchy, either by using white-spaces or tabs for each block. Each block can only have either the tabs or (any number of) white spaces.

```
for item in list:
    print item

if flag:
  raise SystemExit
```

In first block of code, i used four white space and in second i used two.

Same is the case for the COMMENTS. Comments must be indented accordingly.

```
print 'Starting module'
if not configs:
    '''
    sys.exit('Error in Configuration files.')
    '''
    pass
```

In this case the line is meant to be commented and python does not complain. Otherwise it will throw error regarding the indentation.